# Make TrueCrypt volume's file updated immediately?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I am using TrueCrypt volume's file with dropbox's syncing. I noticed dropbox only syncs when I unmount the volume's file so I think TrueCrypt only updates the file when it's unmounted as well. I only unmount the volume when I leave my PC so it would be a bad thing if one day my PC suddenly turns off due to some unexpected reasons, I would probably lose all on progress files.
So, I wonder if I can make the volume's file updated whenever there is something changed in the volume then the volume's file will always be updated to the latest version ?

Comment: NOTE: TrueCrypt is an obsoleted, unsupported, and unmaintained package!

Comment: @mdpc, show us a working alternative, and we'll pay attention to your exclamation points. until then Truecrypt remains the only choice for folks that need its feature set.

Comment: There are many alternatives out there now...including somebody that has basically taken over the truecrypt code.  Google is your friend!

Answer (score 2):

That is probably not behavior you can easily achieve, but there may be a hack.

When a file is opened for write, and data is written to it, eventually the [write lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the file is released. At this time, the file metadata like Modified Date are updated.

When files are created, deleted, renamed, or changes are saved to them, an [OS event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147323%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is fired, detailing the type of change, and what directory it affected. Programs like Dropbox Sync establish ["watchers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on certain directories so they are notified when something changes. Sync notices the change, and starts its routine. A Size change would not be detected, because the volume is of static size. The important take-away is that only when a file change has completed, does it fire a directory event that sync will notice.

When you mount a Truecrypt volume, a [read/write lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) is established on the volume, unless it it mounted as Read-only. This lock remains until the volume file is dismounted. Once the volume is mounted, your PC can access a file on the volume, using the volumes own filesystem, and open it for write. When that file is saved or closed, the metadata is updated and a directory event is fired, but it indicates the file that was changed by its mounted location (eg z:\MyFiles\File1.doc). Dropbox has never heard of that directory before, and is not listening for changes in it. The write lock on the volume file itself however has not released, because the volume is still mounted for write access, and its metadata has not changed.

Note that even if sync did watch for changes on z:\MyFiles\ (the mounted location of a file within the volume) it would decrypt the file and store it in plaintext on Dropbox.

In your case, you are updating the filesystem within your truecrypt volume, and the data is being written to the binary blob inside your volume file. This changes the state of the file, but does so in a way that does not fire a directory event. only when the file is dismounted does the write lock get released, and a directory event fired.

After having looked into the issue, I have a theory that you can work around the issue by creating or editing a file within the sync'ed folder. I have no idea if it will work, and it is a dirty hack, so use at your own discretion.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060685/how-does-dropbox-synchronization-work) indicates that Dropbox Sync uses [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and [rdiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rdiff) to perform differencing on the folder, and can update binary blobs in place, without replacing the whole file. That means that in theory, if a Directory event was fired while the volume was mounted, that the changes since mount would be uploaded.

This approach is dangerous however, because an incomplete save could be in progress, and might result in truncated or corrupt data being synched up. [Disk Write caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer#Write_acceleration) on the interior volume may make it hard to determine when data has been completely flushed to disk. That's part of why waiting for dismount is a very good idea, since dismount flushes the write cache immediately. Even if the disks cache is disabled, there is still a danger that the interior filesystem is not in a stable resting state at the instance the differance is calculated, which could corrupt your volume on the dropbox end.